# How to use hashmap to return multi valued parameter in rest api

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, api, hashmap

I am trying to pass multi-valued parameters in request param and expecting results as below. I am using `@RequestParam List<String>` in the controller to return multi-valued parameters but I am trying to figure how can return the list of employee details in the response as shown below.

### Http Request: /list/id?employee_ids=E123,E765

I am getting below response:

```
{
  "Employees": [
    {
      "EmployeeID": "E123,E765",
      "EmployeeName": "John"
    }
```

Expected Results:

```
{
  "Employees": [
    {
      "EmploeeId": "E123",
      "EmployeeName": "John"
    },
    {
      "EmploeeId": "E765",
      "EmployeeName": "Peter"
    }
 ]
}
```

Pojo:

```
    private String employeeId;

    private String employeeName;
```

Service:

When a list of employee id's are passed, I should get employee id and name

'Employee table contains: EmployeeId and EmployeeName as columns'

Controller:

```
       @GetMapping(value = "/id")
         public ResponseEntity<EmployeeResponse> getEmployee(@RequestParam List<String> employee_ids , @RequestHeader Map<String, Object> headers) {
         log.info("Received request with headers: {}", headers);
         ResponseEntity<EmployeeResponse> response = ResponseEntity.ok(getEmployee.employees(employee_ids
));
         log.info("Responding to request with response: {}", response);
         return response;
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you simply ask how to integrate your spring-boot application with database. I recommend checking Spring Data project. It has great documentation and requires very little code.

Comment: @kkotula, I have rephrased my question, I want to return multiple employees in a list when the request parameters are , separated. How can I return that? and the response should be JSON format.  Please help!

Comment: Add this method also in question (getEmployee.employees(employee_ids)) - it's related to your DAO layer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I use hashmaps in my routes:

```
    Map<String, Object> pdata = new HashMap();
    pdata.put("schedules", schedSVC.getSchedules());
    pdata.put("webuser", userSVC.getActiveUser());
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using JdbcTemplate 
use the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate object
then you have the method NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, params);
just need to add the query with the relevant list